# Amazon RDS Multi-AZ - Access denied error

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have created an AWS RDS MySql using Amazon *RDS Multi-AZ*. The database has been created with one writer and two reader instances. But When I try to login to the database from ec2 or  from my laptop, I am getting the below error

> "Access denied for user 'admin'@'c-11-22-33-44.hsdi1.oh.comacast.net'
> (using password:Yes)

I have created another database with just one instance and the login is working.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means you did not type your password right. You can first type possible special characters in the password in a text editor to confirm the keyboard is not the cause.

Comment: I have reset my password multiple times and the password didn't work. Not sure what was wrong with the password. But after your answer, I reset the password and it works. Thank you.